# Displacement Map: After Effect to Lottie

Tags: after-effects, animation

Now displacement maps don't work for Lottie (by Airbnb), but is there a way to still make them work?
Like the `random()` function on the opacity of a frame doesn't work by default either, but it works when I convert the expression to keyframes `Animation > Keyframe assistant > Convert expression to keyframes`.

Is there any way to make this work for displacement maps as well? I would like to make a glitch effect on an image and I don't know any other way but with a displacement map.

If it is possible to break up the image in random squares and move them while fading in/out I guess I would have the same glitch effect more or less.

Any help to get me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Billy! Probably a good idea!

Comment: It's going to have to be a workaround. To break up the image you could use a collection of alpha mattes and vary their opacity, with duplicates of your original layer with their position offset random amounts.